# CSS Flexbox do we always need to set display property?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

When I was trying to align elements into a row setting flexDirection property wasn't really doing anything

```
 <div style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    <div>hi</div>
    <div>hello</div>   
 </div>
```

The elements appeared in a column as they were without the style.

However, when I added `display: flex` the elements started to behave as expected (aligned in a row rather than column)

```
<div style={{ flexDirection: 'row', display: 'flex' }}>
   <div>hi</div>
   <div>hello</div>
</div>
```

Looking at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ It states about the display property:

> display
> This defines a flex container; inline or block depending on the given value. It enables a flex context for all its direct children.

Does this mean we need to always set `display` property for the container element to start respecting flexbox rules, and otherwise they are pretty much ignored? (Also since it states that flex is applied to direct children meaning it's not transitively applied to all the children just the immediate/direct children of the element right?).

Comment: `flexDirection` requires a `display: flex`. So yes, you need to have `display: flex` :)

Comment: Yes, `flex` rules only work on a container that has `display:flex;` on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, both of your answer to your questions are right.

1. `display:flex` is mandatory, and without it, all flex related attributes will be ignored.
2. Yeah, if it is applied to all the children, it would be quite cumbersome.